# How to get the screen position of an active workbook?

Tags: vsto, position

I would center a form in an ActiveWorkbook, how to get the screen/window position of the workbook?

Comment: found some information at http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/FormPosition.htm, but it doesn't work well;

Answer (score 1):

C# example..

```
private void setFormPos(Form frm)
{
   int top = Application.Top + Application.PageSetup.TopMargin + Application.PageSetup.HeaderMargin + Application.Commandbars["Ribbon"].Height;
   int left = Application.Left + Application.PageSetup.LeftMargin;
   frm.Left = (left / 2);
   frm.Top = (top / 2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Didn't find a good solution but found an acceptable one:

```
int top = Application.Top + Application.PageSetup.TopMargin + Application.PageSetup.HeaderMargin + Application.Commandbars["Ribbon"].Height;
int left = Application.Left + Application.PageSetup.LeftMargin;

Form popup = new Form{ Top = top, Left = left, StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual, Width=400, Height=300};
popup.Show();
```