# How to get the size (width and height) of the area with excel vsto c# excluding the ribbon area?

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio-2012, vsto

How to get the size (width and height) of the area with excel vsto c#,
excluding the ribbon area? This is the area shown with red marker below:

[image]

Comment: In what units do you need the measurements to be displayed??....inches?......centimeters?......number of rows/columns?..........

Comment: I need the size in pixels as usual.

Comment: The following link might be helpful,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1618256/how-to-get-the-screen-position-of-an-active-workbook

Answer (score 0):

This code should work,

```
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet
Dim _with1 = ws.PageSetup

sngWidth = _with1.Application.Width
sngHeight = _with1.Application.Height
```