# Excel 2016 and newer VBA: how to maximize a chart within/to the worksheet size?

Tags: excel, vba, size, worksheet

In https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6gII.png and [How to get the size (width and height) of the area with excel vsto c# excluding the ribbon area?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23566875/how-to-get-the-size-width-and-height-of-the-area-with-excel-vsto-c-sharp-exclu) a similar question has already been put.

Excluding all GUI elements outside/around the "inner/client" worksheet area, e.g. without the ribbon, "X/ok/fx" + cell contents, Sheet menu, "Ready + Record Macro" footer line + frame heights, left + right border + frame widths, etc.

And together with [How to get the screen position of an active workbook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1618256/how-to-get-the-screen-position-of-an-active-workbook) neither of these links has answered my needs yet. Or their instructions do not work for me, because neither of the `.PageSetup.*Margin` values corresponds to my worksheet "inner/client" OR "outside/GUI" borders + frames + overhead sizes.

I know, by writing

```
With ActiveChart.Parent    'access the chart container = the Shape
   .Left = 0
   .Top = 0
   .Width = 4 * 72         'fixed size example
   .Height = 3 * 72        'fixed size example
End With
```

I can set the chart position + size, in this example to a fixed size of 3 * 4 inches.

But HOW TO GET/fetch the whole currently visible dynamic worksheet "inner/client" size (at least once a method call) ?

In order to set the chart size, so that it covers/uses the whole currently visible dynamic worksheet "inner/client" size (at least once a method call). Hopefully: nothing more (no scrollbars shifting needed to see the whole chart), nothing less (no unneccessary "tiny" chart) ?

[I know, that size assignment will work for me only "for a moment" until a workbook resize happens. So I'll have to adjust the chart size again (and again (and again ...)), e.g. by using a timer (or a system timer). Or is there some "anchor/chain/nail" chart property, so that it ALWAYS keeps up with the "inner/client" worksheet size (within the workbook) ?]

Thanks for your help

Comment: Not an answer,  but have you considered using a chart sheet, as apposed to a floating chart?

Answer (score 2):

This is about as good as you can do.

```
Sub SizeChartToWindow()
  Dim VisibleRange As Range
  Set VisibleRange = ActiveWindow.VisibleRange
  
  Dim UsableRange As Range
  Set UsableRange = VisibleRange.Resize(VisibleRange.Rows.Count - 1, _
    VisibleRange.Columns.Count - 1)
  
  With ActiveChart.Parent
    .Left = UsableRange.Left
    .Top = UsableRange.Top
    .Width = UsableRange.Width
    .Height = UsableRange.Height
  End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks, that helped me a lot.

This also takes care of the worksheet scrollbars "scrolled away", wonderful.

And the right + bottom remainder of 0.00 .. 0.99 * cell sizes is "good enough" (and I have reduced the cell width to match the cell height = 20 pixels in order to reduce that remainder effect).

:)))